# Converting Method to Generic Method?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have created a Method shown below,

```
public BOEod CheckCommandStatus(BOEod pBo, IList<string> pProperties)
{
    pBo.isValid = false;
    if (pProperties != null)
    {
        int Num=-1;
        pBo.GetType().GetProperty(pProperties[0].ToString()).GetValue(pBo, null);
        if (ifIntegerGetValue(pBo.GetType().GetProperty(pProperties[0].ToString()).GetValue(pBo, null).ToString(), out Num))
        {
            if (Num == 1)
                pBo.isValid = true;
        }

    }
    return pBo;
}
```

I need to convert this  method, in such a way that it should accept all Type of Objects(now i am accepting only Objects of type "BOEod").

As i am newbie to .Net so don no exactly how to use Generics. Can i accomplish this using Generics.?

Solution Something like this:

```
public T CheckCommandStatus<T>(T pBO, Ilist<string> pProperties){..}
```

Here Main thing is i need to change the Property of the Passed Object(pBO) and return it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need `BOEod` to implement an interface which defines `IsValid`.

You would then add a generic constraint to your method to only accept objects implementing that interface.

```
  public interface IIsValid
  {
      bool IsValid{get;set;}
  }
```

....

```
  public class BOEod : IIsValid
  {
      public bool IsValid{get;set;}
  }
```

....

```
public T CheckCommandStatus<T>(T pBO, IList<string> pProperties) 
where T : IIsValid{..}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public BOEod CheckCommandStatus<T>(T pBo, IList<string> pProperties) where T : IBOEod
{
    pBo.isValid = false;
    if (pProperties != null)
    {
        int Num = -1;
        string propValue = pBo.GetType().GetProperty(pProperties[0].ToString()).GetValue(pBo, null).ToString();
        if (ifIntegerGetValue(propValue, out Num))
        {
            if (Num == 1)
                pBo.isValid = true;
        }
    }
    return pBo;
}

public interface IBOEod
{
    bool IsValid { get; set; }
}
```

All the types you want to pass to this method must implement the `IBOEod` interface.